# Child association back to parent is not loaded

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

I have two models associated with has_many and belongs_to.
Loading with Repo.preload works fine but I noticed the child doesn't have the association back to the parent
 -- seeing Ecto.Association.NotLoaded.

Do I have to preload the child association back to the parent as well?
Is there a way to have the both association linked up from the parent preload call?

(I am using Ecto 2.0 rc5.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do I have to preload the child association back to the parent as well? Is there a way to have the both association linked up from the parent preload call?

As Elixir Maps (and therefore Structs) are immutable, it's not possible to have cycles in it which is what you need to have references back from a child to its parent.

The way I usually work around this is to either pass the parent explicitly along with the child to any function that requires access to both, or preload one more level of association (but this approach wastes memory if you already have the parent association loaded somewhere):

```
Repo.get(Post, 1) |> Repo.preload([comments: [:post]])
```

This will make all the comments of the `Post` to have a copy of the `Post` embedded in them (but those posts won't have *their* comments loaded).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the Ecto approach to cyclic relationship.